# How to partially update local state value?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problme updating local state depending on certain condition the state is simply staying the same

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
    car: '',
    fule: 'Benzine',
  });
  
const handleChange = (e) => {
   setState({ ...state, [`${e.target.name}`]: e.target.value });
 };
 
 const addCar = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (select === 'type2' && state.fule === 'Benzine') {
      setState({ ...state,  fule: 'diesel' });
    }
  console.log(state);
  };
```

Comment: witch line of code is not updating ur state? `if (select === 'type2' && state.fule === 'Benzine')` or the `handleChange` component? if the `if` then simply it could be that the `if` statement returns a `false` hence the code, in this case `setState`, never triggers. drop a `console.log("Triggered")` in the `if` above the `setState`. If it never gets triggered then it could be an issue with the `if` itself as, for example, what is `select`?

Comment: also, if you think the state did not change because of `console.log(state)` INSIDE the `addCar` method, that changes the state, then u will not see it change. The state remains the same untill the component re-renders. What that means is no matter where you trigger the `setState` since the state will remain the same, for the rest of the function, or function tree, till every proccess is done and the component restarts. If you wanna see the state if it changes, then just do a `console.log(state)` outside any function OR inside of `useEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also repurpose `useReducer` to behave like the old `this.setState` api:

```
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(
    (prevState, payload) => ({ ...prevState, ...payload }),
   {}
  );
  
  // Now you can do 

  setState({ a: "hello" })
  // or
  setState({ b:"world" })
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the old reference as

```
setState(oldState => ({...oldState, fule: 'diesel'}))
```

in this way, oldState lost the reference and will be take as new value

Comment: I did this,  but it didn't work.

Comment: how are you implementing the change?

Comment: i will make a sand code sandbox and update the question

Comment: This `setState` function is for class not a functional component. he is clearly using a functional component

Comment: haha the hook support the prevState callback https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate  :D